# JdbcPagingItemReader unable to read all data

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to read data from oracle DB and write data to postgresql DB.

With below configuration, only 250 records are read and written to DB while there are over 100k records in source DB. What am I doing wrong?

I am using spring boot-2.2.5 and spring batch.

Another thing which I have noticed is that

```
if chunk/page size = 500 , 250 records are read
if chunk/page size = 1000 , 500 records are read
if chunk/page size = 2500 , 1250 records are read
```

Configuration is as below:

```
@Bean
Job job() throws Exception {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("importJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .flow(importPersonDetails())
            .end()
            .build();
}


Step importPersonDetails() throws Exception {
    return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("importPersonDetails")
            .<Person, Person>chunk(500)
            .reader(personPagingItemReader())
            .writer(personWriter())
            .listener(new StepListener())
            .build();
}

JdbcPagingItemReader<Person> personPagingItemReader() throws Exception {

            OraclePagingQueryProvider oraclePagingQueryProvider = new OraclePagingQueryProvider();
            oraclePagingQueryProvider.setSelectClause("id,first_name,last_name,birth_date");
            oraclePagingQueryProvider.setFromClause("person_details");
            oraclePagingQueryProvider.setWhereClause("is_alive='Y'");

            Map<String, Order> sortKeys = new HashMap<>(1);
            sortKeys.put("id",Order.ASCENDING);

            oraclePagingQueryProvider.setSortKeys(sortKeys);

            JdbcPagingItemReader<Person> personJdbcPagingItemReader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<>();
            personJdbcPagingItemReader.setDataSource(sourceDatasource);
            personJdbcPagingItemReader.setPageSize(500);
                            personJdbcPagingItemReader.setQueryProvider(oraclePagingQueryProvider);
            personJdbcPagingItemReader.setRowMapper(new PersonRowMapper());
            personJdbcPagingItemReader.afterPropertiesSet();

            return personJdbcPagingItemReader;
    }

    JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> personWriter() {
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> personJdbcBatchItemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
        personJdbcBatchItemWriter.setDataSource(targetDatasource);
        personJdbcBatchItemWriter.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<Person>());
        personJdbcBatchItemWriter.setSql(QUERY_INSERT_PERSONS);
        personJdbcBatchItemWriter.afterPropertiesSet();
        return personJdbcBatchItemWriter;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration seems right, maybe if you could share more code it would be helpful to provide you with more insights.

One thing I suspect besides that this a distributed transaction, is your RowMapper. Maybe you are calling **ResultSet**'s **next**() method for every row, which makes your reader always skip to the next Row in the resultSet.

Hope this helps